# Не работает focus() элементов в браузерах

Tags: javascript

Для примера в "Google переводчике" вставляется текст но без  нажатия и ввода, например пробела в поле (er8xn) перевод не происходит.
в чем проблема?  Заранее благодарю за подсказку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
 function setValues(el, values) {
    el.value = "";
    el.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keypress', {'key':'Shift'} ));
    el.focus();
    el.click();
    el.value = "привет привет привет.";
    el.autocomplete = "on";
    console.log(el.value);
}
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('er8xn');
const timeout = 1000;
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(setValues, timeout * i, elements[i], i);
}
```

Comment: Поля убирал, но результата небыло

Comment: Java не относится к данной задаче

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том, что нужно сообщить элементу, что текст был изменён. Например, так

```
textarea.dispatchEvent(new InputEvent('input', {bubbles: true, cancelable: false, inputType: 'insertFromPaste'}));
```

Comment: Спасибо, да помогло